# I need help fixing a ValueError in a simple random number game

Tags: python, error-handling

I created a simple number guessing game and I'm trying to fix a bug when inputing nothing accidentally.

When the program asks to take a guess, if the user hits enter without inputting a number then I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/tom/Documents/Automate with Python/RandomNumberGame.py", line
>   13, in 
>       guess = int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I'd like it to print 'Please enter a number' instead.

I've new to programming and have started reading "Automate the boring stuff with Python". Thanks in advance!

The original code did not include

```
elif guess == ' ':
     print('Please enter a number')
```

but the goal is make the program say that if the input is left blank

I tried adding:

```
guess = int(input()) or str(input())
```

without any progress

## guess the number game

```
import random
print('Hello, What is your name?')
name = input()
print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 1000, You have 10 guesses to figure it out. Good luck!')
secretNumber = random.randint(1,1000)

print('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

for guessesTaken in range(1,11):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())


    if guess < secretNumber: 
          print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
          print('Your guess is too high.')
    elif guess == ' ':
          print('Please enter a number')
    else:
          break #This condition is for the correct guess

if guess == secretNumber:
          print('Good job ' + name + '! You guessed the number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
          print('Too many guesses, The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: Since `guess` is a number, it can never be equal to a string. If you want to allow empty input, you need to check for that *before* you convert it to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also don't want to lose a try if the user just pressed enter without entering a number. You can use a try-except within a `while True:` block like this

```
#code till this
for guessesTaken in range(1,11):
    print('Take a guess.')
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a number')
            continue
#rest of your code
```

This will allow the user to continue with the game if he pressed enter accidentally while the number of tries remains the same.

Full code:

```
import random
print('Hello, What is your name?')
name = input()
print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 1000, You have 10 guesses to figure it out. Good luck!')
secretNumber = random.randint(1,1000)

print('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

#code till this
for guessesTaken in range(1,11):
    print('Take a guess.')
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a number')
            continue
#rest of your code

    if guess < secretNumber:
          print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
          print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
          break #This condition is for the correct guess

if guess == secretNumber:
          print('Good job ' + name + '! You guessed the number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
          print('Too many guesses, The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw that bug right before you posted. However, now when I input a number all it says is 'take a guess'. It doesn't indicate whether the secret number is higher or lower

Comment: @tl93 It is working fine for me. I have updated my answer to include the full code. Try that.

Comment: Ok after fixing syntax, Ive got it to work. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The variable `guess` is an integer value because you are converting the input into an integer: `guess = int(input())`. If the input is a space, or any other invalid string (cannot be parsed into a number), a `ValueError exception` is raised - that's why you get that error message.

You can handle when specific exceptions occur in Python using a `try/except` block. It works like so:

```
try:
  # execute some code
except SomeException:
  # handle the exception
```

The code in the `try` block will try to be executed, and if running the code results in the exception `SomeException` being raised, the code in the `except` block will be run.

In your specific case, what you want to do is to handle the `ValueError` exception, so you could just wrap the relevant code in a `try/except` like so:

```
...
for guessesTaken in range(1,11):
    print('Take a guess.')

    try:
        guess = int(input())
        if guess < secretNumber: 
              print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretNumber:
              print('Your guess is too high.')
        elif guess == ' ':
              print('Please enter a number')
        else:
              break #This condition is for the correct guess
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number')
...
```

If you want invalid inputs to not take up a guess, you can implement the game like so:

```
...
guessesTaken = 1
while True:
    print('Take a guess.')

    try:
        guess = int(input())
        if guess < secretNumber: 
              print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretNumber:
              print('Your guess is too high.')
        elif guess == ' ':
              print('Please enter a number')
        else:
              break #This condition is for the correct guess
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number')
        continue # go back to the start of loop (without incrementing guessesTaken)

    guessesTaken += 1
    if guessesTaken >= 10:
        break
...
```